# right to left language in eclipse (Persian)

Tags: android, eclipse, right-to-left

I want to use right to left language in eclipse  in some button in eclipse how can I do it ?
i mean some thing like Persian or Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has no problem with them . but there is 2 important things :

1. you must address your string from Strings.XML file .
2. in android that lower than 4 you have to use Right to Left language support Rom .

Comment: its make no different .